# Ruby on Rails : Prawn: Positioning table is not working, getting undefined method 'position='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, prawn

I am trying to position a table on right side but getting

```
undefined method 'position='
```

Here is my sample code:

```
table data , position: :right do
  rows(0).font_style = :bold
  cells.style :align => :right
  cells.borders = []
end
```

but as per  prawn document  http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf‎   above code should run. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured it out. The master branch of prawn gem has that fixed.
 I added

```
gem 'prawn', :git => "https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn.git", :ref => '8028ca0cd2'
```

instead of

```
gem 'prawn'
```

Now its working and the code matches with the manual they provided